# Cannot upgrade RubyGems 1.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Why is the following happening, and how can I sort it?

On OS X Leopard (v10.5.6):

```
$ ./script/server 
Rails requires RubyGems >= 1.3.1 (you have 1.2.0). Please `gem update --system` and try again.
$ sudo gem update --system
Updating RubyGems
Nothing to update
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't hit this issue myself but I've seen this as a possible solution:

```
$ sudo gem install rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-1.3.0
1 gem installed
$ sudo update_rubygems
```

This should let you install the updating via the specific updater gem.

Referenced here: [updating rubygems](https://wincent.com/wiki/Updating_to_RubyGems_1.3.0_on_Mac_OS_X_Leopard_10.5.4)

Comment: This is a chicken-and-egg problem: you want to upgrade from 1.2, because it has bugs. But one of the things that is broken in 1.2 is upgrading ...

Comment: @paulthenerd update_rubygems said it installed the newest version, but after I run gem -v it still return the older version

Comment: Daniel it could be a load path issue if you run gem env what does it show under GEM PATHS?